# Postgresql 9.3 json features support in npgsql

Tags: c#, npgsql, postgresql-9.3

Will npgsql support json manipulation features from Postgresql 9.3?
Can't find any information about this topic on official site.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL 9.3's JSON features are handled by the database engine in the database process - not by the SQL provider(NpgSQL). NpgSQLis responsible for sending the queries to the server and reading the results, not for the actual parsing of the query. Therefore, it does not need to support the JSON manipulation features - it is all done inside the database process.

<s>Retrieving JSON results is a whole different story altogether. [.NET's DbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not contain a JSON type, and the CLR itself does not contain a JSON type, so I doubt NpgSQLwill be able to convert JSON columns in the result to actual JSON. NPG can't do it unless the Microsoft add this feature to .NET, and I believe Microsoft will only add this feature if they add native JSON support to SQL Server - which I don't see happening anytime soon...</s>

So, you can run JSON query with NpgSQL and use all the JSON manipulation the database supports, <s>but if you want to retrieve JSON columns from a query you have to parse the JSON yourself(for example with [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json))</s>

Comment: This isn't entirely correct. Although DbType doesn't support new additions, we have our own NpgsqlDbType which is mapped to DbType where appropriate and if a mapping isn't possible it is mapped to DbType.Object. You can check the current mapping in the "Supported data types" section of our user manual: manual.npgsql.org  The actual problem here is that we didn't start to work on json support yet. But I hope we can add support for it pretty soon.